# Compare columns of 2 files, replace values in different column within one file with values from 1 column in another file Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have searched but could not find anything similar. I have a space delimited TXT file and a tab-delimited CSV file like below

```
file1.txt(space delimited)
a b c d e f
b1 2 3 4 5 6
c7 8 9 3 2 1
d6 2 3 5 9 9

file2.csv (tab delimited)
f   G   h   s
d6  0.2 0.7 9
b1  3   8   2
c7  2   2   7
```

I need to check column 1 in both files. if any column 1 value in file2 is equal to column 1 value in file1, 
I want to replace the value in column 3 of file 1 with the value from column 4 of file 2 and write the whole content to
a new file. the headers can be anything so I will not be able to call column by name. It does not have to be in pandas and hopefully, there is a better way if the file is large

My Current code

```
import pandas as pd

f1 = pd.read_csv("f1.txt",delimiter =" ", header = None)
f2 = pd.read_csv("f2.csv",delimiter =" \t", header = 0)
with open("rr.csv", "w") as f:
    for i in f2.iloc[:, [0]].values:
        for x in f1.iloc[:, [0]].values:
            if i == x:
                f1.iloc[:, [2]].values = f2.iloc[:, [3]].values
                f1.to_csv(f, sep = " ", index = False)
            else:
                f1.to_csv(f, sep = " ", index = False)
```

Expected result:

```
a b c d e f
b1 2 9 4 5 6
c7 8 2 3 2 1
d6 2 7 5 9 9
```

I did it in pandas but I am not getting my intended result
what I got was this (I truncated because it is too long)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
b1 2 3 4 5 6
c7 8 9 3 2 1
d6 2 3 5 9 9
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
b1 2 3 4 5 6
c7 8 9 3 2 1
d6 2 3 5 9 9
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
b1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this does what you need. A larger data sample would have helped. This script assumes two things:

First that there are always the same number of columns in the respective file, and that those files are always delimited by the same characters (space, and tab accordingly)

The script loads each line from file one, strips the newline, splits the line on space, then reads the entire second file line at a time, splitting it on tabs and doing the data checks/writes as needed. At the end of the second file, the pointer is reset to the beginning of the second file, and then the first file brings in the next line to repeat the process.

file1.txt

```
a b c d e f
b1 2 3 4 5 6
c7 8 9 3 2 1
d6 2 3 5 9 9
```

file2.txt

```
f   G   h   s
d6  0.2 0.7 9
b1  3   8   2
c7  2   2   7
```

parse.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
out_f = open("output.txt", "w+")

for l_f1 in f1:
    test_line_1 = l_f1.strip("\n").split(" ")
    for l_f2 in f2:
        test_line_2 = l_f2.strip("\n").split("\t")
        if test_line_2[0] == test_line_1[0]:
            test_line_1[2] = test_line_2[3]
            out_f.write("\t".join(test_line_1) + "\n")
    f2.seek(0,0)

f1.close()
f2.close()
out_f.close()
```

output.txt

```
b1  2   2   4   5   6
c7  8   7   3   2   1
d6  2   9   5   9   9
```

Comment: This is good but there may be fewer columns in one file of the other but I can handle that. Also, it is possible that no value in the column may be present once compared.

Comment: You can add some simple testing to deal with special circumstances.

Comment: yes, sure I intend to. But append means it will keep adding to the output even if I change the column whose value I want to use. e.g instead of col 3, I use col 2 of file 1. The result will have the 1st appended values before the values for the new col. Better to use w+ for writing